# RDP-servers freezing

Tags: windows, azure, windows-server-2016, rdp

We are running an RDP-farm with four terminal servers (Windows Server 2016). On the servers the main software running is our ERP-software, some users are also running the O365-suite. Let's say we have +-30 users running on each server. From time to time one the four servers randomly freezes (not one specific in particular). We can do nothing else than rebooting in the Azure-controlpanel.
Software running on servers is:
- Trend Micro Anti Virus
- O365
- ERP

On the servers there is not 1 process that acts suspicious (high load). What's the best aproach to troubleshoot this, we're a bit stuck...?

Comment: What are the specs of the servers?

Comment: It's the Azure Standard_DS13: 8vCPU, 56GB Ram, 112GB SSD

Comment: TRY and TEST to UNINSTALL the TM Agent. We had such effects with WFBS and NeatSuite; just test, if it's solved, make a case and/or debug the error by yourself.